# Per Network Namespace Quagga OSPF

Tags: network, quagga

I'm new to the Quagga and I'm wondering if it is possible to run a different OSPFd daemon per linux network namespace. My goal is to present a different logical OSPF router to external routers per network namespace.

For example, if I have two network namespaces; red and blue. Eth0=nsred and Eth1=nsblue. Eth0/nsred would be connected to external router1 and eth1/nsblue would be connected to external router2.

Can anyone point me towards documentation on how to do this or know of a better way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get a per namespace instance of quagga running by specifying namespace specific options per daemon. For example,

```
Zebra:
/usr/lib/quagga/blue/zebra -d -f /etc/quagga/zebrab.conf -A 127.0.0.1 -P 2000 -i /var/run/quagga/blue/zebra.pid -z /var/run/quagga/blue/zserv.api

OSPFd:
/usr/lib/quagga/red/ospfd -d -f /etc/quagga/ospfdb.conf -A 127.0.0.1 -P 2001 -i /var/run/quagga/blue/ospfd.pid -z /var/run/quagga/blue/zserv.api
```

I'm sure there is a better way but this makes it functional. I need to do some work on the VTY options but using telnet to make the ospfd configurations works.

Answer (score 2):

You can run anything in a network namespace with "ip netns exec".

So it should just be a matter of writing some scripts to launch your routing daemon in different network namespaces and with different configuration/data files.

Comment: Creating the scripts to launch Quagga in a per namespace with the appropriate config files is the part I'm looking for assistance with. Have you ever done something similar that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't have experiance with Quagga but I assume you have an init script, systemd unit or something like that which starts it. I would suggest making a copy of that and using it as a starting point passing a different configuration file and using ip netns exec to run the actual daemon.